# How can I redirect when it gets the exception in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, exception

In laravel ,how should I code the exception?

```
 class DetailController extends Controller 
 { 

     public function index() {

         $user_id = Request::get('id'); 
         $user = User::find($user_id); 

         if($teacher) { 
             return view("detail",compact(["user"]));
         } 

         return view("top");      
         // "Undefined variable: AAA (View:/Users/user2006734/lesson/lesson/resources/views/top.blade.php)"    
     }
 }
```

---

When user_id is null,I want to make it redirect top page...

Using `Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);`

The Error does not occur but Redirected page is always blank.

Comment: the error shows , in your `top.blade.php` you have defined variable `$AAA` that is undefined

Comment: format your code please

Answer (score 1):

check Request has parameter , if not then redirect or render different view

```
 public function index() {
      if(Request::has('id')){

         $user_id = Request::get('id');
         $user = User::find($user_id);
         return view("detail", compact(["user"]));

      }else{
         return view("top");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Is good solution. In addition I would check if request has "id" and if it is not empty or not null, because id can be on request but not filled..regards

Answer (score 1):

`Route::redirect('/here', '/there', 301);` is for redirectiong routes via `web.php`.

In your controller use

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

to redirect to the route named `home`